# Flutter: How to navigate to another screen for each grid item pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to navigate to another page for every grid item pressed. How can I do this? I have tried to research on the best way to do this with no success. Thank you in advance.

I have dart file for each item (screen_one.dart, screen_two.dart etc). I don't know how to apply the navigation for every items.

here is my grid file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class GridDashboard extends StatelessWidget {
  Items item1 = new Items(
      title: "Calendar",
      subtitle: "March, Wednesday",
      event: "3 Events",
      img: "assets/calendar.png");

  Items item2 = new Items(
    title: "Groceries",
    subtitle: "Bocali, Apple",
    event: "4 Items",
    img: "assets/food.png",
  );
  Items item3 = new Items(
    title: "Locations",
    subtitle: "Lucy Mao going to Office",
    event: "",
    img: "assets/map.png",
  );
  Items item4 = new Items(
    title: "Activity",
    subtitle: "Rose favirited your Post",
    event: "",
    img: "assets/festival.png",
  );
  Items item5 = new Items(
    title: "Forms",
    subtitle: "",
    event: "",
    img: "assets/todo.png",
  );
  Items item6 = new Items(
    title: "Settings",
    subtitle: "",
    event: "",
    img: "assets/setting.png",
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Items> myList = [item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6];
    var color = 0xff453658;
    return Flexible(
      child: GridView.count(
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 18,
          mainAxisSpacing: 18,
          children: myList.map((data) {
            return Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(color), borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    data.img,
                    width: 42,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 14,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    data.title,
                    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 8,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    data.subtitle,
                    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white38,
                            fontSize: 10,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 14,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    data.event,
                    style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white70,
                            fontSize: 11,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }).toList()),
    );
  }
}

class Items {
  String title;
  String subtitle;
  String event;
  String img;
  Items({this.title, this.subtitle, this.event, this.img});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Items` class create another variable named screen, Which would be of the type `Widget`. I assume your using a GridView.builder and constructing each item as a button or something simular. If that's the case, inside your onPressed/onTap function use the Code

```
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute<Widget>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return myList[index].screen;
      }
  )
  );
```

alternatively instead of having your screen variable of type `Widget` have it as a `String` and inside your `MaterialApp` declare this

```
routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
    '/screen1': (BuildContext context) => new Screen1(),
    '/screen2' : (BuildContext context) => new Screen2(),
    '/screen3' : (BuildContext context) => new Screen3(),
    '/screen4' : (BuildContext context) => new Screen4()
  },
```

and each string inside item would correspond to one of these.

This is an example of what your code might look like.

```
    List<Item> items = [
    new Item(
        title: "Calendar",
        subtitle: "March, Wednesday",
        event: "3 Events",
        screen: CalendarScreen,
        img: "assets/calendar.png"),
    new Item(
      title: "Groceries",
      subtitle: "Bocali, Apple",
      event: "4 Items",
      screen: GroceriesScreen,
      img: "assets/food.png",
    ),
    new Item(
      title: "Locations",
      subtitle: "Lucy Mao going to Office",
      event: "",
      screen: LocationScreen,
      img: "assets/map.png",
    ),
    new Item(
      title: "Activity",
      subtitle: "Rose favirited your Post",
      event: "",
      screen: ActivityScreen,
      img: "assets/festival.png",
    ),
    new Item(
      title: "Forms",
      subtitle: "",
      event: "",
      screen: FormsScreen,
      img: "assets/todo.png",
    ),
    new Item(
      title: "Settings",
      subtitle: "",
      event: "",
      screen: SettingsScreen,
      img: "assets/setting.png",
    )
  ];

  var color = 0xff453658;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(
      child: GridView.count(
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 18,
          mainAxisSpacing: 18,
          children: items.map((data) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute<Widget>(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return data.screen;
                }));
              },
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(color),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(
                       data.img,
                       width: 42,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 14,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      data.title,
                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 16,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 8,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      data.subtitle,
                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white38,
                              fontSize: 10,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 14,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      data.event,
                      style: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white70,
                              fontSize: 11,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList()),
    );
```

Comment: Hi @Lachlan, you have confused me completely, can you show me a full implementation of either ways?

Comment: @blackbird i updated the answer to show what the first option might look like. After implementing the code above, add an additional variable to the Items class named 'screen' and the code should navigator to that variable

Comment: @blackbird if you want to go with the second option, its pretty much the same except 'screen' would be of type String and not of type Widget. With the second option you will need to declare your routes under your materialApp widget as shown in the answer above.

Comment: Hi @Lachlan, can you show me how to add an additional variable to the Items class named 'screen' and the code should navigator to that variable, for each individual screen?

Comment: @blackbird Where are you declaring your 'Items' class ?

Comment: It should look something like this class `Item {
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  final String event;
  final String image;
  final Widget screen;

  Item(
      {this.title,
      this.subtitle,
      this.event,
      this.image,
      this.screen});
}`

Comment: Hi @Lachlan, how do I end up calling the item click to go to the specific screen, I am  really stuck using the widget method? am pretty new to flutter sorry i ddnt say

Comment: @blackbird i updated the code above to show what your code should look like